# SQL Table and column Parser for stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2000

Is there an application , which can parse a given set of stored procedures (SQL Server 2000) and  gets all tables and associated columns that are being used in it.
The stored procedure can have tables from different databases.

Output should be like 
TableA 
   columnA
   columnC
   columnD

TableB 
   columnE
   columnF
   columnG

I have written an small application using Database Edition GDR Any one interested can refer to http://tsqlparsergdr.codeplex.com

Comment: I don't think regular expression is the right solution, you need a SQL Parser instead, check this article: http://www.dpriver.com/blog/list-of-demos-illustrate-how-to-use-general-sql-parser/get-columns-and-tables-in-sql-script-net-version/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [SHOWPLAN_ALL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa259203.aspx) setting and parse the output.

Comment: please define "does not work". or better yet - define what works :)

Comment: Why it did not work for me is because most of the stored procedures that i am working on , i do not have all the DB they refer to.
and SHOWPLAN_ALL seems to work only if you have all the DB present.
Its a kind of analysis work that i need to do.

Answer (score 2):

- **UPDATE - 20 Jan 2009** *
- Visual Studio DB Professional Edition shipped with a full T-SQL script DOM parser
- http://blogs.msdn.com/gertd/archive/2008/08/21/getting-to-the-crown-jewels.aspx

Not a concrete solution - but a line of thought.

Considered sysdepends as a potential solution - but it is notoriously unreliable at containing *all* the dependent object information.

but how about something Lex/Yacc derived?  There are a few commercial parsers e.g.

> http://www.sqlparser.com/download.php

Not looked for open-source implementation but I think I would look for that route.  Here's how I started my search:

> http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=sql+lex+yacc+parse

BNF syntax for ANSI SQL can be found here:

> http://savage.net.au/SQL/

With a lex implementation of choice, this seems a relatively straight forward engineering problem from here.  (albeit with some heavylifting if you want to support MS SQL extensions)

Comment: http://www.sqlparser.com/download.php Looks great but cannot buy it. Need some sort of Open source or freeware.

Comment: O'Reilly's YACC & Lex book has a sample of a SQL parser based on yacc.  (http://safari.oreilly.com/9781565920002/sql_parser_code)  You may find other public implementations.  That a commercial product even exists tells you that it is a scarce resource.

Comment: Finally was able to create one using database Edition GDR.. http://tsqlparsergdr.codeplex.com

Comment: Hey rsapru, thanks for taking the time to check back in - glad you got the DB Edition parser to work...  Happy Holidays!

Answer (score 1):

Decided to create an small application using Regex to satisfy my current needs.

Thank  you all for your responses.

Answer (score 1):

sp_depends Worked perfectly for me.
It showed what table or SP might be affected by my changes

Comment: This works a lot better now (SQL Server 2008). The Q is tagged SQL Server 2000 though where dependencies are very ropey.

Answer (score 0):

sp_depends  should help

Answer (score -1):

You could **call the stored procedures programmatically** (in a development environment) and **get the resulting columns**. Maybe you have a naming convention in order to avoid calling insert and update procedure. You'll have to find way to set the right parameters too.

**Note:** I think a 100% reliable solution is technically impossible, because of the way stored procedure (can) work.

Look at this example:

```
[...]
@MyDate datetime

AS

    IF (day(@MyDate) = 1)
    BEGIN
        SELECT * FROM MyFirstTable
        RETURN
    END

    IF (@MyDate > getdate())
        SELECT MyID, MyText FROM MySecondTable WHERE ADate > @MyDate
    ELSE
        EXEC Other_StoredProcedure @MyType, @MyDate
```

So there are two problems: the resulting columns could differ and you'll have to follow recursively other stored procedures.

Comment: The parsing of output has way too many flaws to be viable.  

Agree with the general note tho' - assuming that you'd parse all explicitly declared proc's there is still potential to implicitly invoke procedures through through dynamic SQL strings - which again you'd have to parse etc.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I was not clear. I don't mean "parsing" the output, but getting the resulting columns in a normal way, simply calling the stored procedure. I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Ok, maybe I've misunderstood the question. But it was not clear for me, what rsapru means by "tell me what all tables and columns within that table are being used.".

Comment: Sorry about my explanation, i just wanted application to get all the table and associated columns as output