# How to Find the list of Stored Procedures which affect a particular column?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, stored-procedures

Im working on this large DB which has a lot of the business knowledge embedded in the SPs[I know!] and there is a lot of chaining between the SPs. i.e one stored proc calling another.

Im want to find out a list of stored procedures which  update a particular column. How would I do that.

Using showplan_All as outlined in 
[SQL Table and column Parser for stored procedures](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/283214/sql-table-and-column-parser-for-stored-procedures) doesnt work for me, because this is a shared dev db.

using a Sp from master db scanning system text as described is not feasible because I dont have access to the master db.

So how can I find this informaion?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Find all stored procedures that reference a specific column in some table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19539696/find-all-stored-procedures-that-reference-a-specific-column-in-some-table)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Have you tried this : `EXEC sp_depends @objname = [table name of the column you are interested in]`.

So for example, if you had a column named `Price` in a table named `Product`, you would execute this: `EXEC sp_depends @objname = N'Product'`.

Simply executing this would give you list of all sps, views, etc which depend on that particular table.

I use this all the time as I work with a db which has over 400 tables :-)

[sp_depends page on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189487.aspx)

Answer (score 16):

From system view **sys.sql_dependencies** you can get dependencies at column level.

```
DECLARE @Schema SYSNAME
DECLARE @Table SYSNAME
DECLARE @Column SYSNAME

SET @Schema = 'dbo'
SET @Table = 'TableName'
SET @Column = 'ColumnName'

SELECT o.name
FROM sys.sql_dependencies AS d
  INNER JOIN sys.all_objects AS o ON o.object_id = d.object_id
  INNER JOIN sys.all_objects AS ro ON ro.object_id = d.referenced_major_id
  INNER JOIN sys.all_columns AS c ON c.object_id = ro.object_id AND c.column_id = d.referenced_minor_id
WHERE (SCHEMA_NAME(ro.schema_id)=@Schema) 
  and o.type_desc = 'SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE'
  and ro.name = @Table
  and c.name = @Column
GROUP BY o.name
```

Comment: This gives accurate results including * also. Thanks.!!

Comment: I have tried this with `SET @Schema = 'dbo'; SET @Table = 'Orders'; SET @Column = 'OrderID'` in the Northwind database, and it returns no results.

Answer (score 8):

Try something like this:

```
use YourDatabase;

select [Name]    
from sys.procedures
where object_definition([object_id]) like '%YourColumnName%';
```

Obviously this has the potential to generate a lot of false positives depending on what the column is named but at least you will have a list of procedures to sift through.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one that works in SQL 2000+; Note that as Andrew noted in his, you will get false positives depending on your column name, but it's a starting place:

```
SELECT DISTINCT o.Name
FROM syscomments c
    JOIN sysobjects o ON c.ID = o.ID
WHERE c.Text LIKE '%ColumnName%'
ORDER BY o.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
use msdb
go
select * from sysjobs j
inner join sysjobsteps s
on j.job_id=s.job_id
where command like '%HBR_INSTRUMENT%'
```