# In SQL Server, how can I find everywhere a column is referenced?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Within my rather large database, I would like to find out everywhere a column is referenced within the entire schema (SPs, functions, tables, triggers...).  I don't want to just do a text search since this will pick up comments and also will find similarly named columns from other tables.

Does anyone know if/how I can do this?  I use SQL Server 2008.

Comment: Check here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686247/how-to-find-the-list-of-stored-procedures-which-affect-a-particular-column

Comment: And if you allow dynamic sql in a proc or directly from the application you stilll may not pick up all the times a particular column is used. Further, SSIS packages may directly reference a column as well.

Comment: I am wondering who on earth thought that Listing of Stored procedures is an answer to the OPS Question???  Totally different questions looking for completely different things!

Answer (score 79):

**Warning:** Even though this is a text-search method, the script I'm going to share has saved me **lots and lots of hours**. It searches inside:

- scalar functions
- table-valued functions
- stored procedures
- views
- triggers

I needed to specify a collation to make it work for me.

```
SELECT
    sys.objects.object_id, 
    sys.schemas.name AS [Schema], 
    sys.objects.name AS Object_Name, 
    sys.objects.type_desc AS [Type]
FROM sys.sql_modules (NOLOCK) 
INNER JOIN sys.objects (NOLOCK) ON sys.sql_modules.object_id = sys.objects.object_id 
INNER JOIN sys.schemas (NOLOCK) ON sys.objects.schema_id = sys.schemas.schema_id
WHERE
    sys.sql_modules.definition COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS LIKE '%{Column Name}%' ESCAPE '\'
ORDER BY sys.objects.type_desc, sys.schemas.name, sys.objects.name
```

The output is like the following:

[image: Output]

**Update**: If you need to search for a certain table, SP, etc. you could use a more specialized query:

```
DECLARE @SCHEMA_NAME VARCHAR(100) = 'dbo';
DECLARE @OBJECT_NAME VARCHAR(100) = 'MY_OBJECT';

SELECT
    sys.objects.object_id,
    sys.schemas.name AS [Schema], 
    sys.objects.name AS Object_Name, 
    sys.objects.type_desc AS [Type]
FROM sys.sql_modules (NOLOCK) 
INNER JOIN sys.objects (NOLOCK) ON sys.sql_modules.object_id = sys.objects.object_id 
INNER JOIN sys.schemas (NOLOCK) ON sys.objects.schema_id = sys.schemas.schema_id
WHERE
    (
           '#' + sys.sql_modules.definition + '#' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS LIKE '%[^a-z_]'+@SCHEMA_NAME+'.'+@OBJECT_NAME+'[^a-z_]%' ESCAPE '\'
        OR '#' + sys.sql_modules.definition + '#' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS LIKE '%[^a-z_]\['+@SCHEMA_NAME+'\].'+@OBJECT_NAME+'[^a-z_]%' ESCAPE '\'
        OR '#' + sys.sql_modules.definition + '#' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS LIKE '%[^a-z_]'+@SCHEMA_NAME+'.\['+@OBJECT_NAME+'\][^a-z_]%' ESCAPE '\'
        OR '#' + sys.sql_modules.definition + '#' COLLATE SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS LIKE '%[^a-z_]\['+@SCHEMA_NAME+'\].\['+@OBJECT_NAME+'\][^a-z_]%' ESCAPE '\'
    )
ORDER BY sys.objects.type_desc, sys.schemas.name, sys.objects.name
```

**P.S.**: Both queries search inside comments too.

Comment: So simple and useful... Thanks!!

Answer (score 19):

i tried this query and it seems to be fine:

```
select 
obj.type REFERENCING_OBJECT_TYPE
 ,SCHEMA_NAME(obj.schema_id) REFERENCING_OBJECT_SCHEMA
 ,obj.name                  REFERENCING_OBJECT_NAME
from sysdepends x
INNER JOIN sys.objects obj ON x.id  = obj.object_id
where depid = object_id('yourSchema.yourTable')
and col_name(depid, depnumber) = 'yourColumn'
```

Answer (score 5):

Best ways to do it are described in [this article](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2999/different-ways-to-find-sql-server-object-dependencies/).

A sample:

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME (referencing_id),
              referenced_database_name, 
       referenced_schema_name, referenced_entity_name
FROM sys.sql_expression_dependencies d
WHERE OBJECT_NAME(d.referenced_id) = 'TableName'
      AND OBJECT_DEFINITION (referencing_id)  LIKE '%ColumnName%'
ORDER BY OBJECT_NAME(referencing_id);
```

Answer (score 2):

Does not show if there is a reference to a temporary table
Example

```
create table dbo.TableName (columnName int  )
go
create procedure dbo.ProcedureOne 
as 

    update dbo.TableName  set columnName = 1

go

create or alter procedure dbo.ProcedureTwo 
as 

    create table #test (dd int)
    update 
        t1
    set 
        t1.columnName = 1
    from 
        dbo.TableName   t1
    inner join
        #test t2 on t1.columnName = t2.dd



SELECT 
        1 As Level
        ,t2.type AS ObjectType
        ,CAST(CONCAT(SCHEMA_NAME(t2.schema_id),'.',t2.name) AS varchar(256)) AS RefName
        ,CAST('' AS varchar(256)) AS RefBy
    FROM 
        SYSDEPENDS t1
    LEFT JOIN 
        SYS.OBJECTS t2 ON t1.id  = t2.OBJECT_ID
    WHERE 
        t1.depid = OBJECT_ID('dbo.TableName')
        AND COL_NAME(t1.depid, t1.depnumber) = 'columnName'
```

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cIjF1.png)

Answer (score 1):

As Luv said this is an old question but I've found two more solutions that may be helpful.

I'm using the [sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677185.aspx) system object that finds all referenced objects and columns in a specified object. You can use the following query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
referenced_schema_name AS SchemaName, 
referenced_entity_name AS TableName, 
referenced_minor_name  AS ColumnName
FROM sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities ('yourrefencingobject', 'OBJECT'); 
GO
```

Which gives the following result:

[image]

Downside of this object is that you'll need to specify a referencing object.

Or do a search like:

```
SELECT DISTINCT object_name(id) 
FROM AdventureWorks2012.dbo.syscomments (nolock) 
WHERE text like '%BusinessEntityID%'
```

Which gives the following result:

[image]

I've also find the following SP that you could use in [this article](http://justgeeks.blogspot.com/2007/10/finding-column-references-in-sql-server.html), but haven't tested it properly:

```
> DECLARE    @string varchar(1000),   @ShowReferences char(1)
> 
> SET @string = 'Person.Person.BusinessEntityID' --> searchstring
> 
> SET @ShowReferences = 'N'
> /****************************************************************************/ /*                                                                    
> */ /* TITLE:   sp_FindReferences                                               */ /*                                                                          */ /* DATE:    18 February, 2004                                               */ /*                                                                          */ /* AUTHOR:  WILLIAM MCEVOY                                                  */ /*                                                                          */ /****************************************************************************/ /*                                                                    
> */ /* DESCRIPTION:  SEARCH SYSCOMMENTS FOR INPUT STRING, OUTPUT NAME OF OBJECT */ /*                                                       
> */ /****************************************************************************/ set nocount on
> 
> declare @errnum         int         ,
>         @errors         char(1)     ,
>         @rowcnt         int         ,
>         @output         varchar(255)
> 
> select  @errnum         = 0         ,
>         @errors         = 'N'       ,
>         @rowcnt         = 0         ,
>         @output         = ''        
> 
> /****************************************************************************/ /* INPUT DATA VALIDATION                                              
> */ /****************************************************************************/
> 
> 
> /****************************************************************************/ /* M A I N   P R O C E S S I N G                                      
> */ /****************************************************************************/
> 
> -- Create temp table to hold results DECLARE @Results table (   Name        varchar(55),   Type        varchar(12),   DateCreated datetime,  
> ProcLine    varchar(4000) )
> 
> 
> IF (@ShowReferences = 'N') BEGIN   insert into @Results   select
> distinct
>          'Name' = convert(varchar(55),SO.name),
>          'Type' = SO.type,
>          crdate,
>          ''
>     from sysobjects  SO
>     join syscomments SC on SC.id = SO.id    where SC.text like '%' + @string + '%'   union   select distinct
>          'Name' = convert(varchar(55),SO.name),
>          'Type' = SO.type,
>          crdate,
>          ''
>     from sysobjects  SO    where SO.name like '%' + @string + '%'   union   select distinct
>          'Name' = convert(varchar(55),SO.name),
>          'Type' = SO.type,
>          crdate,
>          ''
>     from sysobjects  SO
>     join syscolumns SC on SC.id = SO.ID    where SC.name like '%' + @string + '%'    order by 2,1 END ELSE BEGIN   insert into @Results  
> select 
>          'Name'      = convert(varchar(55),SO.name),
>          'Type'      = SO.type,
>          crdate,
>          'Proc Line' = text
>     from sysobjects  SO
>     join syscomments SC on SC.id = SO.id    where SC.text like '%' + @string + '%'   union   select 
>          'Name'      = convert(varchar(55),SO.name),
>          'Type'      = SO.type,
>          crdate,
>          'Proc Line' = ''
>     from sysobjects  SO    where SO.name like '%' + @string + '%'   union   select 
>          'Name' = convert(varchar(55),SO.name),
>          'Type' = SO.type,
>          crdate,
>          'Proc Line' = ''
>     from sysobjects  SO
>     join syscolumns SC on SC.id = SO.ID    where SC.name like '%' + @string + '%'    order by 2,1 END
> 
> IF (@ShowReferences = 'N') BEGIN   select Name,
>          'Type' = Case (Type)
>                     when 'P'  then 'Procedure'
>                     when 'TR' then 'Trigger'
>                     when 'X'  then 'Xtended Proc'
>                     when 'U'  then 'Table'
>                     when 'C'  then 'Check Constraint'
>                     when 'D'  then 'Default'
>                     when 'F'  then 'Foreign Key'
>                     when 'K'  then 'Primary Key'
>                     when 'V'  then 'View'
>                     else Type
>                   end,
>          DateCreated
>     from @Results
>     order by 2,1 END ELSE BEGIN   select Name,
>          'Type' = Case (Type)
>                     when 'P'  then 'Procedure'
>                     when 'TR' then 'Trigger'
>                     when 'X'  then 'Xtended Proc'
>                     when 'U'  then 'Table'
>                     when 'C'  then 'Check Constraint'
>                     when 'D'  then 'Default'
>                     when 'F'  then 'Foreign Key'
>                     when 'K'  then 'Primary Key'
>                     when 'V'  then 'View'
>                     else Type
>                   end,
>          DateCreated,
>          ProcLine
>     from @Results
>     order by 2,1 END
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I would like to avoid using sys.sql_dependencies because this feature will be removed in a future version of Microsoft SQL Server.
I also cannot use OBJECT_DEFINITION function because all my objects are encrypted.
So I came up with the following query which seems pretty simple and works for me so well that I even wrapped it to the function:

```
-- =============================================
-- Description: Gets all the stored procedures, functions and triggers referencing the specified column.
-- Example:     SELECT * FROM dbo.UFN_GET_SP_FN_TR_REFERENCING_COLUMN(N'dbo', N'MY_TABLE', N'MY_COLUMN');
-- =============================================
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.UFN_GET_SP_FN_TR_REFERENCING_COLUMN 
(
    @SchemaName sysname,
    @TableName sysname,
    @ColumnName sysname
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS 
RETURN

    SELECT R.referencing_schema_name + N'.' + R.referencing_entity_name AS referencing_entity_name
    FROM sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities(@SchemaName + N'.' + @TableName, 'OBJECT') AS R 
        INNER JOIN sys.objects AS O 
            ON R.referencing_id = O.object_id
    WHERE O.[type] IN ('FN'/*SQL scalar function*/, 'IF'/*SQL inline table-valued function*/, 'TF'/*SQL table-valued-function*/, 'P'/*SQL Stored Procedure*/, 'TR' /*SQL DML trigger*/)
          AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities (R.referencing_schema_name + N'.' + R.referencing_entity_name, 'OBJECT') AS RE WHERE RE.referenced_entity_name = @TableName AND RE.referenced_minor_name = @ColumnName);

GO
```

Comment: What about Tables that reference that column - for example a foreign key ?

Answer (score 0):

Hello Although this is an old post I was able to combine few tips from above got something like this below which was help full for me. The reason had I create this one is the column I was in lot of tables so it did not provide me clear output.

```
SELECT 
      SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id)+'.'+[name] as objectname
      ,type_desc
     ,referenced_schema_name AS SchemaName
,referenced_entity_name AS TableName
,referenced_minor_name  AS ColumnName
  FROM [sys].[all_objects] ob cross apply sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities ( SCHEMA_NAME(schema_id)+'.'+[name], 'OBJECT') e

  where is_ms_shipped = 0 and type_desc in ('AGGREGATE_FUNCTION'
,'SQL_SCALAR_FUNCTION'
,'SQL_INLINE_TABLE_VALUED_FUNCTION'
,'SQL_STORED_PROCEDURE'
,'SQL_TABLE_VALUED_FUNCTION'
,'SQL_TRIGGER'
,'VIEW')
and name !='sp_upgraddiagrams'
and referenced_entity_name  = 'table name'
and referenced_minor_name = 'columnname'
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a slight tweak on @alex's TV-UDF to include views also:

```
/*
    Source: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47775531/852956
    Gets all the stored procedures, functions and triggers referencing the specified column.

    SELECT * FROM Utility.ft_SelectSprocFuncAndTrigrRefs(N'BrakeRotor', N'BrakeRotors', N'BrakeRotorNumber');
*/
CREATE FUNCTION Utility.ft_SelectSprocFuncAndTrigrRefs
(
    @SchemaName sysname,
    @TableName sysname,
    @ColumnName sysname
)
RETURNS TABLE
AS 
RETURN

    SELECT QUOTENAME(R.referencing_schema_name) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(R.referencing_entity_name) AS ReferencingEntityName
    FROM sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities(@SchemaName + N'.' + @TableName, 'OBJECT') AS R 
        INNER JOIN sys.objects AS O 
            ON R.referencing_id = O.object_id
    WHERE O.[type] IN (
                'FN'/*SQL scalar function*/,
                'IF'/*SQL inline table-valued function*/,
                'TF'/*SQL table-valued-function*/,
                'P'/*SQL Stored Procedure*/,
                'TR' /*SQL DML trigger*/
            )
          AND EXISTS(
                    SELECT 1
                    FROM sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities (R.referencing_schema_name + N'.' + R.referencing_entity_name, 'OBJECT') AS RE
                    WHERE RE.referenced_entity_name = @TableName AND RE.referenced_minor_name = @ColumnName)

    UNION SELECT QUOTENAME(VIEW_SCHEMA) + N'.' + QUOTENAME(VIEW_NAME) AS ReferencingEntityName
        FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW_COLUMN_USAGE
        WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = @SchemaName
          AND TABLE_NAME = @TableName
          AND column_name = @ColumnName
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

Had to do this today and came up with the following:

```
declare @obj sysname = 'schema.table';

select p.referencing_entity_name, c.*
from sys.dm_sql_referencing_entities(@obj, 'object') as p
cross apply sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities(
   concat(p.referencing_schema_name, '.', p.referencing_entity_name), 
   'object'
) as c
where c.referenced_id = object_id(@obj)
    and referenced_minor_name in ('yourColumn');
```