# Find all stored procedures that reference a specific column in some table

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, find

I have a value in a table that was changed unexpectedly. The column in question is `CreatedDate`, which is set when my item is created, but it's being changed by a stored procedure.

Could I write some type of `SELECT` statement to get all the procedure names that reference this column from my table?

Comment: Have a look at the `sys.all_sql_modules` table. In particular the column titled `definition`

Comment: Possible duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/686247/how-to-find-the-list-of-stored-procedures-which-affect-a-particular-column/14822831#14822831

Comment: I found https://stackoverflow.com/a/8757152/9695286 this answer more accurate

Answer (score 95, accepted):

One option is to create a script file.

Right click on the database ***-> Tasks -> Generate Scripts***

Then you can select all the stored procedures and generate the script with all the sps. So you can find the reference from there.

Or

```
-- Search in All Objects
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID),
definition
FROM sys.sql_modules
WHERE definition LIKE '%' + 'CreatedDate' + '%'
GO

-- Search in Stored Procedure Only
SELECT DISTINCT OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID),
object_definition(OBJECT_ID)
FROM sys.Procedures
WHERE object_definition(OBJECT_ID) LIKE '%' + 'CreatedDate' + '%'
GO
```

Source [SQL SERVER – Find Column Used in Stored Procedure – Search Stored Procedure for Column Name](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2012/07/19/sql-server-find-column-used-in-stored-procedure-search-stored-procedure-for-column-name-part-2/)

Comment: Does this just find objects / procedures with a defined parameter that matches the `WHERE` clause, or would this also find references to `MyTable.SomeColumn` within the objects themselves?

Comment: Perfect! Works great for me. Thanks

Comment: Doesn't work well if the name is a substring of some other names.

Answer (score 39):

If you want to get stored procedures using specific column only, you can use try this query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT Name
FROM sys.Procedures
WHERE object_definition(OBJECT_ID) LIKE '%CreatedDate%';
```

If you want to get stored procedures using specific column of table, you can use below query :

```
SELECT DISTINCT Name 
FROM sys.procedures
WHERE OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID) LIKE '%tbl_name%'
AND OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID) LIKE '%CreatedDate%';
```

Answer (score 22):

You can use [ApexSQL Search](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_search.aspx), it's a free SSMS and Visual Studio add-in and it can list all objects that reference a specific table column. It can also find data stored in tables and views. You can easily filter the results to show a specific database object type that references the column

[image]

*Disclaimer: I work for ApexSQL as a Support Engineer*

Comment: This doesn't give just the column named FirstName in a specific SP, but in any SP. This is fine until you have the same column name in use in several tables, views,.... There is no tool I know of that can find every place a specific column is referenced.

Answer (score 7):

You can use the **system views** contained in **`information_schema`** to **search in tables**, **views** and (unencrypted) **stored procedures** with one script. I developed such a script some time ago because I needed to search for field names everywhere in the database.

The script below first lists the tables/views containing the column name you're searching for, and then the stored procedures source code where the column is found. It displays the result in one table distinguishing **"BASE TABLE", "VIEW" and "PROCEDURE"**, and (optionally) the source code in a second table:

```
DECLARE @SearchFor nvarchar(max)='%CustomerID%' -- search for this string
DECLARE @SearchSP bit = 1 -- 1=search in SPs as well
DECLARE @DisplaySPSource bit = 1 -- 1=display SP source code

-- tables
if (@SearchSP=1) begin  
  (
  select '['+c.table_Schema+'].['+c.table_Name+'].['+c.column_name+']' [schema_object], 
            t.table_type 
  from information_schema.columns c
  left join information_schema.Tables t on c.table_name=t.table_name
  where column_name like @SearchFor 
  union
  select '['+routine_Schema+'].['+routine_Name+']' [schema_object], 
         'PROCEDURE' as table_type from information_schema.routines
  where routine_definition like @SearchFor
        and routine_type='procedure'
  )
  order by table_type, schema_object
end else begin
  select '['+c.table_Schema+'].['+c.table_Name+'].['+c.column_name+']' [schema_object], 
         t.table_type 
  from information_schema.columns c
  left join information_schema.Tables t on c.table_name=t.table_name
  where column_name like @SearchFor 
  order by c.table_Name, c.column_name
end     
-- stored procedure (source listing)
if (@SearchSP=1) begin      
    if (@DisplaySPSource=1) begin
      select '['+routine_Schema+'].['+routine_Name+']' [schema.sp], routine_definition 
      from information_schema.routines
      where routine_definition like @SearchFor
      and routine_type='procedure'
      order by routine_name
    end
end
```

If you run the query, use the "result as text" option - then you can use "find" to locate the search text in the result set (useful for long source code).

**Note** that you can set `@DisplaySPSource` to `0` if you just want to display the SP names, and if you're just looking for tables/views, but not for SPs, you can set `@SearchSP` to `0`.

**Example result** (find `CustomerID` in the Northwind database, results displayed via LinqPad):

[image: Sample Result]

**Note** that I've verfied this script with a test view `dbo.TestOrders`
and it found the `CustomerID` in this view even though `c.*` was used in the `SELECT` statement (referenced table `Customers` contains the `CustomerID`and hence the view is showing this column).

---

**Note** for **LinqPad** users: In **C#,** you can use `dc.ExecuteQueryDynamic(sqlQueryStr, new object[] {... parameters ...} ).Dump();` and have the parameters as `@p0` ... `@pn` inside the query string. Then you can write a static extension class and save it under **My Extensions** to be used in your LinqPad queries. The data context can be passed from the query window as `DataContextBase dc` via parameter, i.e. `public static void SearchDialog(this DataContextBase dc, string searchString = "%")` inside a public static extension class (in LinqPad 6, it is `DataContext`). Then you can rewrite the SQL query above as a string with parameters and invoke it from the C# context.

Comment: Thanks for great effort. Almost perfect. FYI - It does not return those `SP` which has `column` reference in `insert into` statement. I found this answer more accurate https://stackoverflow.com/a/8757152/9695286.

Comment: @Karan - I tried the solution you mentioned, but it returns no results. I have left a comment there.

Answer (score 2):

try this..

```
SELECT Name
FROM sys.procedures
WHERE OBJECT_DEFINITION(OBJECT_ID) LIKE '%CreatedDate%'
GO
```

or you can generate a scripts of all procedures and search from there.

Answer (score 2):

i had the same problem and i found that *Microsoft* has a *systable* that shows [dependencies](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-dynamic-management-views/sys-dm-sql-referenced-entities-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).

```
SELECT 
    referenced_id
    , referenced_entity_name AS table_name
    , referenced_minor_name as column_name
    , is_all_columns_found
FROM sys.dm_sql_referenced_entities ('dbo.Proc1', 'OBJECT');
```

And this works with both `Views` and `Triggers`.

Answer (score 2):

-- Search in All Objects

```
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID),
definition
FROM sys.sql_modules
WHERE definition LIKE '%' + 'ColumnName' + '%'
GO
```

-- Search in Stored Procedure Only

```
SELECT DISTINCT OBJECT_NAME(OBJECT_ID)
FROM sys.Procedures
WHERE object_definition(OBJECT_ID) LIKE '%' + 'ColumnName' + '%'
GO
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
FROM   sys.all_sql_modules
WHERE  definition LIKE '%CreatedDate%'
```

Answer (score 0):

> You can use the below query to identify the values. But please keep in mind that this will not give you the results from encrypted stored procedure.

```
SELECT DISTINCT OBJECT_NAME(comments.id) OBJECT_NAME
    ,objects.type_desc
FROM syscomments comments
    ,sys.objects objects
WHERE comments.id = objects.object_id
    AND TEXT LIKE '%CreatedDate%'
ORDER BY 1
```